# Blue, Red and pink Materia

Tags: unity, materials

Hi guys i just started using unity recently but today after working on some animation blending, most (not all) prefabs changed to look like this:

[image: ss]

What's the cause, and how can i fix it? i tried creating a new project then copied my Asset directory to it but still. also when i try importing a new character i still see the same.

Material structure.
[image]

Comment: Can you show us how the material on the object is configured?

Comment: This could be caused by many things. 1) the material attached to the model is using a shader that doesn't exist/is corrupted 2) the material is using a texture that has been deleted, or that Unity can't find. I think you should try reassigning the material to the corresponding objects or redragging the prefab in the scene. In the screenshot you provided, you selected the prefab, not the object in the scene(the materials look alright, for the prefab, but not for the obj in the scene)

Comment: I tried importing new character and its still same. its fine with older version of unity though.

Comment: Did you update Unity by any chance? Some updates will just not work with older shaders.

Comment: Yes. i guess that was the issue.